# Sending logo type image with text tweet in twitter

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am newbie  to twiiter api with iphone and I am working on project in which I have to post logo type image in text post area in twitter.Like we can do in facebook Share functionality with the help of "attachments". so am asking may we post image as we can do in facebook post and if yes, how it will be done?

Comment: You have to rely on a 3rd party to upload the image and get back the URL, then use a Twitter client to post both text and image. This library integrates a Twitter + Twitpic client to do that: https://github.com/jaanus/PlainOAuth

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at twitters blog post here:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media

Heres also a discussion about it with some useful tips:

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1059

those tutorials end up with what you want: http://twitter.com/oauth_dancer/status/103216165765136386

Answer (score 0):

Check this Twitter open source Project

http://code.google.com/p/tweetero/

Open Terminal - Enter : http://code.google.com/p/tweetero/source/checkout

i hope it consists of all twitter features.