# post media and text together on twitter

Tags: android, twitter

i am developing an application that needs to post images and text simultaneously on twitter but on doing googling? i can't find the right link.canyone provide me some tutorial or link?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to provide more details such as, what language your using and what you have so far.

Comment: i am able to post text as status but i wanna post both image and text simultaneously . and i am using android

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate: [Sending logo type image with text tweet in twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145821/sending-logo-type-image-with-text-tweet-in-twitter)

Have a look at twitters blog post here:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media

Heres also a discussion about it with some useful tips:

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1059

those tutorials end up with what you want: 
http://twitter.com/oauth_dancer/status/103216165765136386

Comment: i have seen it but i am not able to understand please provide some link?